# Laravel eloquent grab user with posts ordered by

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am playing around with Laravel and I have this code. It returns all of a users posts, based on the provided username.

*Controller*

```
 $posts = User::whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail()->posts;

 return View::make('users.index')->with($posts);
```

*View*

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)

      {{ $post->title }}
      {{ $post-owner->username }}
      // etc etc

 @endforeach
```

How would I go about adding an `orderBy()` to my query? I would like the posts to be ordered by newest first. This was my attempt :(

```
User::whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail()->posts->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
```

Or is there a better way to go about  doing this?

**EDIT**

*User Model*

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

*Post Model*

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: everything looks good! what are the errors?

Comment: `firstOrFail` should return your a `User` model if it found one or a `ModelNotFoundException` if it can't find anything

Comment: This is the error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy()`

Comment: That error should only pops out when you're using `posts->` only because `posts` without the bracket will return a `Collection` object. Have you tried adding the brackets to `posts`? so that it will be `posts()->` and see what are the errors?

Comment: I changed `posts` to `posts()` and the page loaded fine but appeared to have no results. When I `dd` it fills the page with gibberish until the browser tab crashes. Looks like [this](http://imgur.com/84Iyjus)

Comment: Alrighty, my very bad! Can you add `get()` to the end of the code? It was careless of me. The `orderBy` only builds the query hence it'll return that gibberish data, the `get()` method will execute the query. Please give it a try

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!!! Seems strange to me why my original query would work... haha `User::whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail()->posts;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62860/discussion-between-oni-and-staysee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is slightly missing the `()` brackets on the relationship!

Try this

```
User::whereUsername($username)
->firstOrFail()
->posts()
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
->get();
```

Note the brackets on `posts()->`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately adding `()` sends my browser into loading limbo and the tab crashes.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your `User` model? You should define your relationship on the `User` model. Afterwards, the relationship method should return an object in which your can chain your fluent queries.

Comment: If you can post your code in github or something, I'd be more than willing to help you on that! :D

Comment: I posted the relations from the models.